# SQL What do I need to group by?

Tags: sql, group-by, count

I am trying to get a better understanding of group by and count in SQL and tried to find the student who has been studying for the second longest time.

I need to also group by s.semester for it to work, just group by s.name alone (which is what I had done initially) does not work - why is this? I know this is right, but am trying to understand why for future practice questions.

```sql
select s.name
from students s
group by s.name, s.semester
having 1 = (select count (gold.name)
from students gold
where gold.name <> s.name
and gold.semester > s.semester
)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

To solve this task, it is not enough to use grouping. You need to use ranking functions.
You will receive the rank of each subsequent student or students, based on the number of semesters.
You can get students by rank using "where".

```
select 
*
from(
     select 
     row_number() over (partition by name_students, semestr order by semestr_count 
     asc) r_n,
     name_students, 
     semestr
     from (
           select name_students, semestr, count(semestr_count) from studies
           group by name_students, semestr
          ) agregate_studies
where r_n = 1
```

Using r_n for get some students top _ n : 2..3